# Why shell output redirect to a random name file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I write a crontab mission to make 3 POST request every 10 minutes by cURL, and here is pseudo:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo `date` >>/tmp/log
curl $a >>/tmp/log
curl $b >>/tmp/log
curl $c >>/tmp/log
```

That is all the code, but after the first echo to my /tmp/log, other output was saved in random file name like "A6E0U9~D", it doesn't happen all the time, I got no clues why.:(

PS. I don't use "$a", I use a raw string which copy from CHROME Dev Tool, and one of them is added below. And every single line's output is good, the only problem is some of the output was redirected to a random name file.

the cURL link is deleted because it contained my login cookie

Comment: You have special characters in urls `$a`, `$b`, of `$c`  (e.g. `';' '\' '&;` or the like that cause your url to be split into multiple words. Double quote your variables `"$a" "$b" "$c"`.

Comment: no, the output is fine, it's not a var in fact, i just make it short to $a to let the code look clean. I copied the curl request from CHROME's developer tool, and every lines of output was good, the only problem is some of them don't redirect to the specfic file.

Comment: Bug report / help request 101: [Minimal, complete, verifiable code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Input. Expected output. Observed output. Posting pseudocode usually hides the real issue.

Comment: post at least one of your full curl commands

Comment: 3 line's curl request is the same except each cookies is different.

Comment: The contain `' '` and `'%'` which will cause the shell fits unless they are properly quoted (e.g. `"$a"`).

Comment: If `$a` contains `-o something`, `curl` will write the output to `something` instead of writing it to stdout.

Comment: If you were using `curl $a`, changing it to `curl "$a"` would probably correct the problem. Since you say you're not, I have no idea how to correct the problem, since you haven't told us what you're actually doing. (An aside: `date >> /tmp/log` is simpler than `echo `date` >> /tmp/log`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a solution, but you can redirect the output of everything at once, rather than repeatedly appending to the same file.

```
#!/bin/sh
{
    date
    curl ...
    curl ...
    curl ...
} > /tmp/log
```

The benefit here is that all the output will appear in the same file, whether that file is /tmp/log or an oddly named file. If you *still* end up with another file aside from /tmp/log, then you know there must be a problem with one of the `curl` calls.

(Note that capturing and re-printing the output of `date` is redundant.)

---

In order to run each `curl` in parallel, you'll need to save the output from each, and concatenate them once all have finished.

```
#!/bin/sh
{
    date
    tmp1=$(mktemp) && curl ... > "$tmp1" &
    tmp2=$(mktemp) && curl ... > "$tmp2" &
    tmp3=$(mktemp) && curl ... > "$tmp3" &
    wait
    cat "$tmp1" "$tmp2" "$tmp3"
 } > /tmp/log
 rm "$tmp1" "$tmp2" "$tmp3"
```

Comment: I tried you solution, it work perfectly. thank you very much. 
 
is it possilbe to add a \n or space between each curl output, except add 2 echo " "? Because I want to change it to curl ... & curl & curl & wait to speed up the script

Comment: Running each `curl` in the background makes managing the output a little more complicated, since you have to save the output from each in order to provide sensibly merged output. I'll add a solution to the answer.